# GLIBC 2.14 installation error: forced unwind support is required - RHEL 7.5

Tags: linux, rhel, amazon-ec2

I have upgraded my RHEL OS from 6.7 to 7.5. After upgrading, I found some issues when trying to run `yum`. Below are the details.

```
# yum repolist

There was a problem importing one of the Python modules                                                                                                                       
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:                                                                                                                   

/lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1)                                                                                        

Please install a package which provides this module, or                                                                                                                       
verify that the module is installed correctly.                                                                                                                                

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the                                                                                                                         
current version of Python, which is:                                                                                                                                          
2.6.6 (r266:84292, Aug  9 2016, 06:11:56)                                                                                                                                     
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17)]                                                                                                                                       

If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to                                                                                                                       
the yum faq at:                                                                                                                                                               
  http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/Faq
```

---

After getting this error, I just installed python2.7 and GLIBC 2.14. But when I am trying to install GLIBC 2.14 from my current GLIBC version 2.12, it is throwing some error. Below are the steps that I am using to install GLIBC 2.14:

1. `tar xvfz glibc-2.14.tar.gz`
2. `cd glibc-2.14`
3. `mkdir build`
4. `cd build`
5. `../configure --prefix=/opt/glibc-2.14`
6. `make`
7. `sudo make install`
8. `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/glibc-2.14/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

In step5, I am getting error. Below are the details:

```
# ../configure --prefix=/opt/glibc-2.14

checking for forced unwind support... no                                                                                                                                
configure: error: forced unwind support is required
```

I am unaware of this error "unwind support is required".Please let me know how to setup/install forced unwind in Redhat 7.5.

Answer (score 0):

> I have upgraded my RHEL OS from 6.7 to 7.5.

Unfortunately, upgrading from 6.7 to 7.5 is not something that is supported. Really weird side effects like this can happen if you run the upgrade tool without first running a `yum upgrade` and a `yum update`. Did you take a look at the [Prepare Your System for Upgrade](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/migration_planning_guide/chap-Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux-Migration_Planning_Guide-Upgrading#migration-prepare_your_system_for_upgrade) guide? The first step is to upgrade your system to the latest minor version in the major version (in this case `6.9`).

If restoring from a backup is not an option, I would suggest contacting RHEL support!